# Rails 3 and DataMapper: group by wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datamapper

I'm having issues using the groupby and distinct queries in RoR3.

If I using this in my controller, all is well:

```
@radgroupchecks = Radgroupcheck.find_by_sql("select * from radgroupcheck group by groupname")
```

But I want to do in rails. I've tried:

```
@radgroupchecks = Radgroupcheck.select("DISTINCT(groupname)").all
```

But that gives me an error: wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)

What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `group` method for grouping in ActiveRecord. I think what you want is this:

```
Radgroupcheck.all.group('groupname')
```

Check out [this link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group) for more information.

BTW, it's better (more conventional, but not necessary) to use camel casing for your classes in Ruby (e.g. `RedGroupCheck`).

**UPDATE: DataMapper**

I haven't used DataMapper before, but looks like you need to write something like this:

```
Redgroupcheck.all(:fields => [:groupname], :unique => true)
```

[This](http://datamapper.org/docs/find.html) might help. (Search for "group" on that page).

Comment: That's my issue, I'm using datamapper. Sorry I forgot that important point!!! Sadly, my db was already in place and was stuck with the table names. J

Comment: @JennyBlunt: BTW, out of curiosity how do you find DataMapper compared to ActiveRecord?

Comment: Thanks, that's what I just found too. It's causing me issues but think that's unrelated to the query. DM... Was forced into it as my db has columns labeled attribute. It took me ages to figure it out but now I've got it, it's far simpler although it needs time to mature. There seem to be only a handful of people writing about it. Worth trying though :)

Comment: @JennyBlunt: what issues is it causing? Any exceptions? I might be able to help.